# Extracting information of GIT repositories

Tags: java, json, git, rest, github

I'm trying to extract information from "plain" git (remote) repositories.

Consider https://github.com/jquery/jquery. You can find there information like:

```
tjvantoll authored Friday at 10:13 PM
timmywil committed Monday at 10:43 PM

build    Release: ensure Sizzle is the latest tag                 12 days ago
src      Wrap: Declare a dependency on the manipulation module    2 days ago
test     Ajax: Support usage without jQuery.event                 2 days ago
[...]
```

I need information like these, but from a git repository, not from github only. Can I use JGit, REST, JSON or something else, to be able to get these information and parse them for author, url, date, etc?
 Are there methods like getAuthor(), getLastCommit(), getDate(), etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/ for JSON - it returns all the commits

Comment: Thanks! Can I also use it for "plain" git repositories or for github only?

Comment: You have to check each time, f.e. bitbucket: [see here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=330796872) and [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs;jsessionid=97BC4FC3FA7DBF6870D8BECE409D1B50.node3)